# Fire Event execute multiple time. titanium android

Tags: android, event-handling, titanium-mobile

I am developing android application with Titanium, android sdk 1.8.0.1.In my application there are three tabs.Every Time when I click on tab my window get refreshed.So my code structure looks like:

```
////// on tab click /////////////////////
var explore = Titanium.UI.createWindow(
{
  //navBarHidden:true,
  backgroundColor:'#f8f8f8'
});explore.open({animated:true});

  ////// m.js  /////////////////
 var explore = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
Ti.App.addEventListener('feed_partial_action',function(e)
{
  alert('inside event')
})
var new = Titanium.UI.createButton(
{

});explore.add(new);
new.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
  var explore_new = Titanium.UI.createWindow(
  {
    navBarHidden:true,
    backgroundColor:'#f8f8f8'
  });explore_new.open({animated:true});

});

    /////// explore_new.js/////////////////
var explore_new = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
Ti.App.fireEvent('feed_partial_action',{page_type:'new'});
```

so my problem is that on first load alert inside the event listner in m.js executed once but when I again call m.js it shows alert twice.on third time it shows alert 3 times and so on and after some time it forcefully close the app.I think event listener of window still open after refreshing widow.So is there any way to handle this problem.Thank you

Comment: How are you passing your window to the Tab? and why you are opening window every time explore.open?

Comment: On tab click I am executing open window.I just edit the question.

Comment: Is that a requirement? Because no need to open window if you are using tabs. Just pass window object to tab.

Comment: I am not using default tab-group functionality in Titanium.

Answer (score 4):

What you have here is a memory leak.
When you add the event listener to Ti.App with the statement

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('feed_partial_action',function(e)
{
   alert('inside event')
});
```

That anonymous function is stored within the Ti.App context (it has to retain a reference to the function so that it can invoke it when the "feed_partial_action" event is fired). That function will not be garbage collected until Ti.App releases its reference to it. Furthermore, it remains tied to the event.

There are several ways to deal with this. I don't know exactly how to tell you how to fix your problem because I don't have a lot of context with the provided code sample. So, here are some solutions. If one of the assumptions below is not correct, please give more detail.

- If the 'feed_partial_action' event is truly supposed to be global event that has one and only one event handler, move 
  `Ti.App.addEventListener('feed_partial_action',function...);` code outside a block that gets executed multiple times.
- If you need to stop receiving the event when the explore window is closed, then move the eventHandler function (the anonymous one) out to a named function or variable and call `Ti.App.removeEventListener('feed_partial_action', myFunction);` when you close the window. The easiest way to do this would be

  ```
  function feedPartialActionCB(e) { alert('inside event'); }
  Ti.App.addEventListener('feed_partial_action', feedPartialActionCB);
  explore.addEventListener('close', function() {
    Ti.App.removeEventListener('feed_partial_action', feedPartialActionCB); 
  });
  ```